# How can I access Windows Vista printer from Ubuntu over the network?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, printer

I just [installed Ubuntu 9.04 on my laptop](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=howtos&id=22) and was able to share a folder on Ubuntu which I can access via Windows Vista, so I know the network connection works fine.

But when I try to connect a network printer from Ubuntu, I can't find my Windows Vista computer on the network and therefore cannot connect to the printer on Vista (although other Vista computers can use the network printer).

Do I need to install Samba on Vista or **what do I have to do to be able to use the Vista network printer from Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Samba installed to be able to print on a Vista shared printer.
In your printer utility (System > Administration > Printing > Samba) go to browse for the Vista PC and that should work